# $\sigma$-product space and $ \Sigma$-product space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Recently, I'm interested in the $\sigma$-product space and $\Sigma$-product space. Is there a survey on $\sigma$-product space and $\Sigma$-product space, which is simple for a beginner? Thanks for any help:)